# delegating RSOP rights

Tags: group-policy

I have delegated RSOP rights for an OU. (In fact I ended up delegating full control). But when the users that I delegated to tries to run RSOP they get 'you do not have permission' error. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/914047

you have to allow DCOM calls to the DCs